# Coldfusion FileUpload function from cfc file not working

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, cfc, cffile, cffunction

I am currently trying to upload a file using a function from a cfc file. I can get the code to work when I just call the `<cffile action="upload">` on the same page. However, I wanted to learn how to call it from a function in a cfc file. I believe there is a problem with the arguments I'm passing to the attributes  of the `<cffile>` tag, but I'm not sure.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="confirm.cfm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="FNAME" size="25" /> <br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="LNAME" size="30" /> <br />
    Upload Attachment File Here: <input type="file" name="fileUpload" 
                                    id="fileUpload" size="30" 
                                    onchange="PassFileName()" /> <br />

    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <input type="reset" name="Reset Form" />
    <div id="filenamesection">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the code that the form is submitting to the confirm.cfm page

```
<cfif isDefined("Form.fileUpload")>
    <cfinvoke component="FileUploadExample"
            method="UploadFile"
            fileToUpload="#Form.fileUpload#"
            sizeMax="50"
            returnvariable="FileNameReturn">
    <cfelse>
            <cflocation url="index.cfm">
    </cfif>
    <h1> Thank for filling out this form </h1>
    <cfoutput>
    <table>
    <h3> Please review and confirm the information below </h3>
    <tr>
        <td> is this the first name you entered </td>
        <td>  #Form.FNAME# </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> is this the last name you entered </td>
        <td>  #Form.LNAME# </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> is this the name of the file you uploaded? </td>
        <td>  #Form.fileName# </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </cfoutput>

    The File <cfoutput> #Form.fileName# </cfoutput> has been uploaded
```

Here is the code from my FileUploadExample.cfc file

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="uploadFile" access="public" output="no" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="fileToUpload" type="string" required="no">

        <cfset var cffile="">
        <cffile action="upload"
                destination="C:\filepath\example\whatevaFolder\"
                filefield="#ARGUMENTS.fileToUpload#"
                nameconflict="overwrite">
        <cfreturn cffile.clientFile>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The error I keep receiving when I upload a file is:

> neotmp84939430443.tmp did not contain a file.

Comment: To isolate the problem, run your cffile code in your .cfm  file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the upload with cffile, it needs a form field name - what you are passing in is the form field *value*. Please see [this link](http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:23351#117413) for the exact method to achieve what you are trying to do.

---

**CFFILE Upload in a CFC**

I keep seeing people get tripped up over this, so here's what the deal is.  The biggest thing you have to remember about cffile's upload is that  no matter what, the filefield **has** to be the name of the form  field  that you're trying to upload.

Example:

Note the lack of pound signs.  That means that you're forcing cffile to go  look for form.something and grab the data stream out of it. So, what do you  have to do if you put it in a CFC?  You can't pass the datastream into a  CFC (you can, but that's not the correct way to do it).  You have to pass  the name of the file field into the cfc instead.

Example CFC:

```
<cfcomponent name="fileio">
  <cffunction name="fileUpload" access="public" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="fileField" required="true" type="string">
    <cfargument name="destination" required="true" type="string">

    <cffile action="upload" filefield="#arguments.fileField#" destination="#arguments.destination#">
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Not the pound signs around arguments.fileField.  Why?  Because you're evaluating the value of arguments.fileField which is actually a string:  'form.something'.  Example usage would be:

```
<cfscript>
  fileObj = createObject('component','fileio');
  fileObj.fileUpload('form.something','c:\');
</cfscript>
```

Comment: So I should remove the pound signs around arguments.fileToUpload in my CFC file?

Comment: No, you should remove them from the form field in the call to your cfc - so just pass the form name in rather than the value.

Comment: That gave me the error:
Element FILETOUPLOAD is undefined in ARGUMENTS. (on line 7)

        ` 6 : <cffile action="upload"
7 :   filefield="#ARGUMENTS.fileToUpload#"
8 :    destination="E:\webs\au\htdocs\users\swat21\FileUploadExample\"
9 : nameconflict="overwrite">`

Comment: You still need to put the form field name in as an argument when you call your cfc, just with no pound signs. It's in cfscript rather than cfml but you'll be able to see that on the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you so much the <cfscript> worked perfectly, I am eternally grateful thank you :)

Comment: No problems, glad to be able to help.